# I would like to save my destination file in .CSV and not in xlsx

Tags: python

I would like to save my destination file in .CSV and not in xlsx
this code works very well but I cannot save the output file in .CSV
I looked on google, but I couldn't find anything

```
# Main function
def classement_top(FILE_SOURCE,FILE_DESTINATION):
    df = pd.read_csv(FILE_SOURCE)
    liste_partant = list(set(df['comp']))
    liste_filtre_partant = []
    for partant in liste_partant:
        source = 'df_partcccant_' + str(partant)
        liste_filtre_partant.append(source)
        vars()[source] = df[df['comp'] == partant]
        vars()[source] = vars()[source].nlargest(5, ['total_teste'])
        top1 = 0
        top2 = 0
        top3 = 0
        top4 = 0
        top5 = 0
        for elem in list(vars()[source]['cl']):
            if elem == '1er':
                top1 = 1
            if elem == '2e':
                top2 = 1
            if elem == '3e':
                top3 = 1
            if elem == '4e':
                top4 = 1
            if elem == '5e':
                top5 = 1
        top5 = top5 + top4 + top3 + top2 + top1
        top4 = top4 + top3 + top2 + top1
        top3 = top3 + top2 + top1
        top2 = top2 + top1

        for i in list(vars()[source].index):
            vars()[source].at[i,'top1'] = top1
            vars()[source].at[i,'top2'] = top2
            vars()[source].at[i,'top3'] = top3
            vars()[source].at[i,'top4'] = top4
            vars()[source].at[i,'top5'] = top5

    liste_variable = []
    for elem in liste_filtre_partant:
        liste_variable.append(vars()[elem])

    final_df = pd.concat(liste_variable)
    final_df = final_df.sort_values(by=['jour', 'comp'], ascending=True)
    final_df.to_excel(FILE_DESTINATION, index=False)
```

Launch of the function
FILE_DESTINATION with the location where we want to save the file
this code works very well but I cannot save the output file in .CSV

```
FILE_DESTINATION = "C:/Users/Utilisateur/Documents/PMU/EXPORT/sorti_teste_1_suite.xlsx"
```

FILE_SOURCE

```
FILE_SOURCE = "C:/Users/Utilisateur/Documents/PMU/EXPORT/teste_1_suite.csv"
classement_top(FILE_SOURCE,FILE_DESTINATION)
```

Comment: final_df.to_csv(...) doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, that's it final_df.to_csv

Answer (score 0):

Use `final_df.to_excel(FILE_DESTINATION, index=False)`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

(moving comment to answer)

Comment: Please accept an answer so this post is removed from the "No Answer" list. Thanks.